# Workaround for passing function to ipcMain and back using React, Redux, Electron

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron

I am trying to load/update data from a local database file at certain times in my application. This file of course must be accessed from the main process, so I send to the main process from renderer and then when the main process returns the data I need, I need to run Redux's dispatch to update my state accordingly. The problem is that my ipcRenderer.on() listener doesn't have context to call dispatch properly. I tried passing a function through to the main process and then back to the renderer, but functions get stripped from ipcRenderer.send.

How can I properly update my state once I receive the data back from the main process? Below isolated chunks of my code.

Main process:

```
ipcMain.on('getSites', (event, args) => {
  db.sites.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    event.sender.send('getSitesSuccess', { data: docs, dispatch: args.dispatch });
  });
});
```

Renderer process:

```
ipcRenderer.on('getSitesSuccess', (event, args) => {
  args.dispatch(args.data);
});

class SiteList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    ipcRenderer.send('getSites', {
      test: 'test',
      dispatch: (data) => { this.props.dispatch(actions.change('sites', data)); }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set up your event listeners inside your class instance (`componentDidMount`). Also, make sure to properly dispose any event listeners once the instance disposes (`componentWillUnmount`).

```
class SiteList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on('getSitesSuccess', this.handleSitesSuccess);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    ipcRenderer.removeListener('getSitesSuccess', this.handleSitesSuccess);
  }

  handleSitesSuccess(event, args) {
    console.log('data', args.data);
    props.dispatch(actions.change('sites', args.data));
  }
}
```

If you are doing a lot of ipc calls (both receive and send), have a look at `redux-electron-ipc` ([link](https://github.com/mariotacke/redux-electron-ipc)). This removes the wiring logic for ipc calls from your actual components and lets you work directly with redux state.

Note: I am the author of this plugin.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Will definitely be implementing your answer. I found your plugin while trying to figure out this bug and kept it open in a tab. Will definitely be taking another look soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this is the best approach, but it turns out restructuring my code a bit was the solution. Instead of having the ipcRenderer.on outside of my component, I just needed to nest it in my constructor for the component. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
class SiteList extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    ipcRenderer.on('getSitesSuccess', (event, args) => {
      console.log('data', args.data);
      props.dispatch(actions.change('sites', args.data));
    });
  }
}
```